Inputting unicode characters into JTextField
In most situations I can enter Unicode characters by typing ctrl-shift-u followed by the hexadecimal character code. So for instance by typing ctrl-shift-u 2264 here in the browser I get "≤". I am using Linux; Windows has a comparable way of entry by holding alt and entering the decimal code for the character on the numpad. I don't know macOS well but I assume there is a similar keyboard combination for entering Unicode characters by code.
When I run a Java program, in particular I am using this demo program from Oracle, none of these methods of entering a Unicode character into a JTextField by keyboard seem to work. I can copy the characters in from another applications (gedit) and paste them in. But I haven't found a way either by trial or by searching the interwebs to type them in directly.
Is there a way to make the JTextField control accept (presumably os-specific) key codes for Unicode characters?
Steps to reproduce the issue on Linux

Compile and run the following application:

import javax.swing.*;
class JTextFieldExample
{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("JTextField Example");
        JTextField t = new JTextField("");
        t.setBounds(10, 10, 400, 30);
        f.add(t);
        f.setSize(420,90);
        f.setLayout(null);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}


Press ctrl + shift + U 2264 + Enter.
You will see that the "≤" character fails to make it into the JTextField.
Now press the same key sequence into a text editor, select and copy the "≤" character to your clipboard, and then paste it into the JTextField. You will see that it gets entered correctly there, proving that the JTextField can in fact display that character, but it fails to process the key sequence correctly.

edit: since many seem to be interested, I am using Debian Testing (Trixie) updated as of 2024.08.22.
$ java --version
openjdk 23-ea 2024-09-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 23-ea+34-Debian-1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23-ea+34-Debian-1, mixed mode, sharing)

The information on windows was sent to me by another user, and I have no information on macs. I hope this information is helpful.

Please put more effort into your writing when posting here. This site is meant to be more like Wikipedia, less like a casual chat room. Proper case & spelling, helps as does editing to avoid run-on sentences and so forth. I made some edits to improve your prose this time.

There really is no such thing as "Unicode" characters as a distinct group. All characters in Java are Unicode characters. What you really mean are the characters beyond the Basic Latin block of Unicode which is also US-ASCII.

(1) Please confirm whether you are using macOS or another Linux? Why did you mention MacOS? (2) According to your description, you should want to use keyboard combinations to enter Unicode characters in JTextField on MacOS. (3) You should open your editor and try to use keyboard key combinations to enter Unicode characters to confirm whether this is a system problem (you used the wrong key combination) or a JTextField problem?

(4) I am using Ubuntu 20.04 Java 21, tested TextInputDemo.java and SpringUtilities.java, no problem, my pom.xml has set <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>  <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding> , (5) My Environment: LANG is
en_US.UTF-8

BTW, using Windows, pressing ALT - +¹ + 2264 is entering the corresponding character ≤ in the demo program you linked to. || ¹ numeric keypad + (not sure if that entry method is enabled by default)

On-screen keyboard?

https://superuser.com/q/1662393/241386, How to type directly with keyboard the U+200C character?, Typing alt codes on keyboard without numeric pad, How do you type Unicode characters using hexadecimal codes?

@phuclv the OP already knows how to type Unicode characters with the keyboard, but is asking why it doesn't work specifically in a JTextField - it works everywhere else, just not in a JTextField. Your links are not much use as the OP already knows that.

Avoid null layouts in Swing Do so and you'll find that your key stroke sequence will work fine

e.g.: import java.awt.*;import javax.swing.*;public class FB extends JFrame {private JTextField tf;private void setGui() {setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);Container cp = getContentPane();JPanel bPanel = new JPanel();tf = new JTextField(10);bPanel.add(tf);cp.add(bPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);tf.requestFocus();}public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {EventQueue.invokeAndWait(() -> {FB f = new FB();f.setGui();f.setSize(200, 100);f.setVisible(true);});}}

@g00se no, I tried your code and it shows exactly the same problem.

Strange. I was able to reproduce the problem with your code and solve it with mine

@g00se I was previously on Linux. The problem could be reproduced on Linux with both your code and mine. Now I've just tried both on Windows. On Windows, both your code and mine work ok. I've just edited the question to show steps only for Linux.

I'm on Linux and have only tested both there

Interesting. If I input certain characters, such as U+00A3 (£) or even something more exotic like the Armenian character U+0531 (Ա), it works! But U+2264 (≤) doesn't work, although it works if I copy & paste it from somewhere else. Tried: Ubuntu 20.04 (where it doesn't work) and Windows 11 Pro (where it works).

(1) USE JTextField t = new JTextField(20); , ctrl + shift + U 2264 + Enter , will get “≤”  In Ubuntu, Will Work fine, (2) use JTextField t = new JTextField(""); will fail.

@life888888 no, in my case, it still fails, no matter whether I use new JTextField(20) or new JTextField(""). When I say it fails, I mean it shows an underlined u followed by 2264 as I type them but then, when I press Enter, it's an empty string.

@k314159  I can reproduce error by your code: new JTextField("") , but When I change to new JTextField(20), It can enter the ctrl + shift + U 2264 + Enter.  (0) My Environment: Ubuntu 20.04 , LANG=en_US.UTF-8. (1) run echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP -> ubuntu:GNOME
(2) run gnome-shell --version -> GNOME Shell 3.36.9
(3) run neofetch -> DE: GNOME, WM: Mutter , WM Theme: Adwaita

I have almost exactly the same as you (except LANG=en_GB.UTF-8, but it still fails even if I do export LANG=en_US.UTF-8)

There really is no such thing as "Unicode" characters as a distinct group. All characters in Java are Unicode characters. What you really mean are the characters beyond the Basic Latin block of Unicode which is also US-ASCII. @BasilBourque
What I really mean is, "a unicode character that is not on my current keyboard." Although I use a US-international keyboard there are still a few unicode characters that aren't on it.

@k314159  (1) List Installed input method framework: im-config -l -> ibus xim
(2) List CUreent input method framework: im-config -m -> default missing ibus ibus
(3) ibus engine -> chewing (When I switch to Chinese input method)
(4) ibus engine -> xkb:us::eng (When I switch to English input method)

BTW, using Windows, pressing ALT - +¹ + 2264 is entering the corresponding character ≤ in the demo program you linked to. || ¹ numeric keypad + (not sure if that entry method is enabled by default) @user85421 I think you are using the windows alt-numpad method here. The windows method uses decimal numbers not hexadecimal. When using this method you should type, alt-8864.

The Windows Unicode input method can be configured to use hex: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_input#In_Microsoft_Windows

@life888888 exactly the same as mine, except I don't use Chinese input method so it's always xkb:us::eng (I don't know why it says us if I'm using the UK keyboard).

List Installed input method framework: @k314159
bash: im-config: command not found

I can't find anything else that can affect it. My Ubuntu can use ctrl + shift + U 2264 + Enter to input "≤" normally, but your Linux cannot input it normally.

My JDK (Temurin JDK 21): Run Command java -version -> (a)  openjdk version "21.0.3" 2024-04-16 LTS  (b)  OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-21.0.3+9 (build 21.0.3+9-LTS) (c)  OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-21.0.3+9 (build 21.0.3+9-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)

And the classic: is the font for the jtextfield able to display the character?

Perhaps some more context would be helpful. I am not a java programmer, and my knowledge of java culture is very, very limited. I am currently compiling and running at command line with "javac TextFieldDemo; java TextFieldDemo". I commented out the line "package components;" because that seemed to introduce issues with being unable to find the "main()" method. I am using no .pom files as that would require familiarity with java culture. I have tried the two suggestions regarding "null layouts", and neither seemed successful.

And the classic: is the font for the jtextfield able to display the character? @JustanotherJavaprogrammer Yes. I can paste any unicode character I want into the JTextField, and it displays normally. I just can't enter the character directly in the JTextField.

@jrv Re: "I think you are using the windows alt-numpad method here." - only the + is from numeric keypad (as I explained); "The windows method uses decimal numbers not hexadecimal." NOT if you use the + from keypad: see Wikipedia or this answer or this - and I sure know what I typed or used since decades !

@user85421 the hex input method only works if you set that registry value. If you don't (and on my PC it wasn't initially set) then it uses decimal instead. Even if you use the + on the numeric keypad.

I build a new VM using debian-12.6.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso, run  apt-get install default-jdk install JDK. JDK 17. then I run  JTextFieldExample again, ctrl + shift + U 2264 + Enter to input "≤" normally.

Is your other machine also a VM? Mine is a physical laptop. I've tried it with other codes: U+2260, 2261, 2262, 2263 all work ok. U+2264 and U+2265 don't work. U+2266 again works ok. Strange! @jrv do you also see this?

(1) My Ubuntu is physical Machine. (2) My Test VM using debian-12.6.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso (GUI Install , Gnome) , It's very fresh and clean as it was just installed.

My laptop has had all sorts of stuff installed, uninstalled, reinstalled, reconfigured etc over several years. Still it puzzles me that this problem happens only with JTextFields and not any other input boxes.

I build a new VM again using debian-testing-amd64-DVD-1.iso (testing) (GUI Desktop, Gnome), run sudo apt-get install default-jdk , sudo apt-get install maven  install JDK And Maven. JDK 21 , Maven 3.8.8 , run mvn clean pacakge (re-compile) , then I run JTextFieldExample again, ctrl + shift + U 2264 + Enter to input "≤" normally. (All English Config, no Chinese input method.)

@k314159 I've tried it with other codes: U+2260, 2261, 2262, 2263 all work ok. U+2264 and U+2265 don't work. U+2266 again works ok. Strange! -jrv do you also see this? I tried u+2260. I can't get ctrl-shift-u, release, 2260 to work but ctrl-shift-u, hold-ctrl-and-shift, 2260 puts in a character, a superscript close parenthesis.The trouble here is that u+2260 is an equals sign with a slash, "≠". I can't get any other codes to produce output, but "2260" consistently outputs " ⁾ ". Very strange.

Test the font file currently mapped to the Swing program. : (1) add Font textFieldFont = t.getFont();         System.out.println("JTextField Font Name: " + textFieldFont.getFontName()); (2) add import java.awt.*; (3) Run JTextFieldExample , get font: JTextFieldExample (4) find physic font: Font font = new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 12);         System.out.println("Font Name: " + font.getFontName());         System.out.println("Physical Font Family: " + font.getFamily()); (4)  Run JTextFieldExample , again , get font : "Dialog"

(5) Linux terminal: fc-match "Dialog" , show: NotoSansCJK-Regular.ttc: "Noto Sans CJK TC" "Regular"
(6) Linux terminal: fc-list | grep "Noto Sans CJK TC" , show /usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto/NotoSansCJK-Black.ttc: Noto Sans CJK TC,Noto Sans CJK TC Black:style=Black,Regular /usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto/NotoSansCJK-Regular.ttc: Noto Sans CJK TC:style=Regular /usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto/NotoSansCJK-DemiLight.ttc: Noto Sans CJK TC,Noto Sans CJK TC DemiLight:style=DemiLight,Regular ..., Test In my Ubuntu.

In Debian 12 testing, (1) Linux Terminal: fc-match "Dialog" , show DejaVuSans.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Book"  (2)  Linux terminal: fc-list | grep "DejaVu Sans" , show
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf: DejaVu Sans Mono:style=Book /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansCondensed-Oblique.ttf: DejaVu Sans,DejaVu Sans Condensed:style=Condensed .... (3) Different fonts may have different appearances corresponding to a certain coded character. (When the default font lacks a certain coded character, a fall back font may be used to display that character. )

@life888888. I added the code (textFieldFont = entry.getFont(); System.out.println("JTextField Font Name: " + textFieldFont.getFontName()); Font font = new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 12); System.out.println("Font Name: " + font.getFontName()); System.out.println("Physical Font Family: " + font.getFamily());) to insertUpdate(). The results for the physical font & family seem like they are not what you were expecting: "JTextField Font Name: Dialog.plain Font Name: Dialog.plain Physical Font Family: Dialog"

@life888888 While I don't know for certain, my guess is that it's not font-related. The reason I say this is because if I paste text, even unusual characters like U+1F003 (mah jong ), in it displays just fine. Now this may be due to font substitution, but to me it looks as though as long as the JTextField tries to display the right unicode, it just works on the display side. What seems to be not functional, at least on my machine, is a way to enter the proper unicode to the JTextField.

For me, ctrl-shift-U works every time, whether I use new JTextField("") or new JTextField(30).  I’m using Debian 6.1.94-1 and Java 22.0.2.  (However, ctrl-shift-E has issues;  it kind of works, but it makes a mess of the text content in the process.)  I have no special fonts installed.

The font only affects the appearance of the Unicode character that will be displayed after you complete the input. It does not affect your input.
